# Gradle Fail to start daemon

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, daemon

After installing Android Studio I have created a new empty project and built it.
But the project doesn't build and show the error below.

I'm using Android Studio every day, on Ubuntu and win7. It's the first time I try it on win10 and I have this error. All my firewalls are disabled and the last stable java jdk version is installed. I need gradle to build my Unity projects.
I've tried to add  -Xmx512m to VM Option, too.

The project hasn't been touched. It's a build error right after the project has been created. I don't have any code to show.

I would like to have the build response to be :'The project is correctly build.'

But i have :

ERROR: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon